Multiple drag and drop rectangular selections on a Matplotlib heatmap / imshow
On a Matplotlib heatmap:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
plt.imshow(np.random.random((16, 16)), cmap='jet', interpolation='nearest')
plt.show()

is there a built-in Matplotlib feature to do a "rectangular selection" with drag and drop, and have the possibility to resize/move the selection later, etc.?
For example by adding a toolbar button that allows to draw a selection rectangle?
NB: I'm  looking for a solution to have multiple selections on the same heatmap.

There's the Poly Editor example in the documentation, with t, d, and i keybindings to toggle edit, delete and insert points. For multiple shapes, combine it to your liking with the Button example  of the documentation.

Thank you @paime. Do you think PolyEditor would be better adapted than https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/widgets/rectangle_selector.html?

Nice, yes the RectangleSelector seems far easier to use. You juste need to create buttons and callbacks to manage multiple ones.

Glad @paime was able to answer your question. Here's an example implementation of the RectangleSelector because Matplotlib doesn't natively support multiple selections.
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.widgets import RectangleSelector
from matplotlib.widgets import Button

class MultiRectangleSelector:
    def __init__(self, ax, canvas):
        self.ax = ax
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.selectors = []
        self.current_selector = None

        self.create_buttons()
    
    def create_buttons(self):
        ax_add = plt.axes([0.7, 0.05, 0.1, 0.075])
        ax_done = plt.axes([0.81, 0.05, 0.1, 0.075])

        self.btn_add = Button(ax_add, 'Add')
        self.btn_done = Button(ax_done, 'Done')

        self.btn_add.on_clicked(self.add_selector)
        self.btn_done.on_clicked(self.done)

    def add_selector(self, event):
        toggle_selector.RS = RectangleSelector(self.ax, self.onselect,
                                               drawtype='box', useblit=True,
                                               button=[1],  # left mouse button
                                               minspanx=5, minspany=5,
                                               spancoords='pixels',
                                               interactive=True)
        self.current_selector = toggle_selector.RS
        self.selectors.append(self.current_selector)

    def onselect(self, eclick, erelease):
        print(f"Start position: ({eclick.xdata}, {eclick.ydata})")
        print(f"End position: ({erelease.xdata}, {erelease.ydata})")
    
    def done(self, event):
        print("Selectors:")
        for i, selector in enumerate(self.selectors):
            extent = selector.extents
            print(f"Selector {i}: {extent}")

        # Disable current selector
        if self.current_selector:
            self.current_selector.set_active(False)
        self.current_selector = None

def toggle_selector(event):
    print(' Key pressed.')
    if event.key in ['Q', 'q'] and toggle_selector.RS.active:
        print(' RectangleSelector deactivated.')
        toggle_selector.RS.set_active(False)
    if event.key in ['A', 'a'] and not toggle_selector.RS.active:
        print(' RectangleSelector activated.')
        toggle_selector.RS.set_active(True)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.imshow(np.random.random((16, 16)), cmap='jet', interpolation='nearest')

multi_rect_selector = MultiRectangleSelector(ax, fig.canvas)
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event', toggle_selector)

plt.show()


What are the buttons within the matplotlib plot are expected to do? How to use them?
